# How to show all data in array using jquery. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, jquery, array

I'm getting all the Data from Array in **Jquery** when I `console.log()` it then it shows me all the data of the array but when I append the data with `<div>` then it only returns me the last value I know that it is an overriding issue but how can I solve this. My array in `console.log()` is

[image]

and my code is

```
<h1>Pakistan</h1>
<?php
$block->storeInAlgolic();
$block->testing();
?>
<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal

        ) {

            $("#order_search").keyup(function () {

                var textinput = $('#order_search').val().substring(0, 20);
                // alert(textinput);

                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('search/index/SearchBoxData') ?>',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {
                            input_val : textinput
                        },
                        success: function(data) {

                            $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
                                $.each( value['hits'], function( ky, val ) {

                                    console.log('ky => '+ky);

                                    console.log('val => '+val);
                                    $.each(val , function(k, va){

                                        console.log('k => '+k);
                                        console.log('va => '+va);

                                        if(k == 'order_no')
                                        {
                                            $("#a1").text(va);

                                        }else if(k == 'customer_name')
                                        {
                                            $("#a2").text(va);
                                        }else if(k == 'customer_email')
                                        {
                                            $("#a3").text(va);
                                        }else if(k == 'all_products')
                                        {
                                            $.each(va , function(g,v){


                                                if(g == 'name0')
                                                {
                                                    $("#a4").text(v);
                                                }else if(g == 'sku0')
                                                {
                                                    $("#a5").text(v);

                                                }
                                                 $('<div class=\'custom-order\'> <h3> Order Number: </h3> <b id=\'a1\'> order ID </b> <br> <h3>Customer Name</h3> <b id=\'a2\'> customer Name </b> <br> <h3>Customer Email</h3><b id=\'a3\'> customer Email </b> <br><h3>Product Name</h3><b id=\'a4\'> Product Name: </b> <br><h3>Product SKU</h3><b id=\'a5\'> Product SKU: </b> <br></div>').appendTo('#asad');
                                                console.log('g => '+g);
                                                console.log('v => '+v);
                                            });
                                        }

                                    });

                                });
                            });
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                            console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
                            }
                   });


                $("#textbox2").val(textinput);
                $("#textbox3").val(textinput);


            });
        });
</script>

<style>
    input[id=order_search] {
        width: 280px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-size: 16px;
        background-color: white;
        /*background-image: url('searchicon.png');*/
        background-position: 10px 10px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
        transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }

    input[id=order_search]:focus {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Animated search form:</p>

<form type="POST">
    <input type="text" id="order_search" name="searchh" placeholder="Search Order by Order_ID">
    <br /><input type="text" id="textbox2"/><br>
    <br /><input type="text" id="textbox3"/>
</form>

<div id ='asad'>Khan</div>


</body>
```

now in the result only last value is shown as you can see in image below [image]
Now how to show all the data?

Comment: refer this link it will help you https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/jquery-how-to-push-specific-key-and-value-in-arrayexample.html

Comment: you can use `myarray.push()` in jQuery

Comment: I have data in my array just want to show in `<div>`

Comment: did you try with appendTo() ?